# mysql select Where (subquery) IN

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql query of type

```
select some_value FROM table WHERE (subquery) IN ( values )
```

which seems to be extremly slow!

I have a mysql table with orders and a second one with the corresponding processing states of them. I want now to show all orders having their last status code = 1 .

table order (id = primary key)

```
id | value
---+-------
1  +  10
2  +  12
3  +  14
```

table state (id = primary key)

```
id | orderid | code
---+---------+-------
1  +  1      +  1
2  +  2      +  1
3  +  2      +  2
4  +  1      +  3
5  +  3      +  1
```

My query is:

```
select order.id FROM order WHERE
( select state.code FROM state WHERE state.orderid = order.id ORDER BY state.id DESC LIMIT 0,1 )     IN ( '1' )
```

It takes roughly 15 seconds to process this for a single order. How to modify the mysql statement in order to speed the query procession time up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Try this one:

```
select s1.orderid
from state s1
left outer join state s2 on s1.orderid = s2.orderid
    and s2.id > s1.id
where s1.code = 1
    and s2.id is null
```

You may need an index on `state.orderid`.

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c924/1)

```
CREATE TABLE state
    (`id` int, `orderid` int, `code` int)
;

INSERT INTO state
    (`id`, `orderid`, `code`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1),
    (2, 2, 1),
    (3, 2, 2),
    (4, 1, 3),
    (5, 3, 1)
;
```

**Query**:

```
select s1.orderid
from state s1
left outer join state s2 on s1.orderid = s2.orderid
    and s2.id > s1.id
where s1.code = 1
    and s2.id is null
```

**Results**:

```
| ORDERID |
|---------|
|       3 |
```

Comment: Hereby I only will get a single order, since LIMIT 0,1 acts on all orders with all states.

Comment: Sorry, did not read the question well enough. Try my updated query.

Comment: Thank you.  It works quite fast! However, as i apply an index on state.orderid the execution time "tends to be zero". Can you comment on the behavior of this index and why this speeds the query up that enormously?

Comment: Simplistically, an index as a sorted list of that column, with a pointer back to the record in the table. E.g. you can find someone by their name quickly in the phone book because it is sorted (indexed) by lastname, firstname. Trying to find someone in the phone book by their phone number is the equivalent of not having an index. You would have to check every entry until you get a match.

Answer (score 1):

in this situation I think you could simply forget of `order`, as all information stays in `state`.

```
SELECT x.id, x.orderid
FROM state AS x
WHERE x.code =1
AND x.id = (
SELECT max( id )
FROM a
WHERE orderid = x.orderid )
```

Maybe would be possible to change your `CRUD` by putting last state directly in `order` table too, this would be the better